# Distutils ignores build/lib on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I have a `setup.py` script which builds files to be installed to the `./build/lib` directory. The files are populated by the `run()` method of my custom `distutils.command.build.build` subclass:

```py
from distutils.command.build import build
from distutils.core import setup

class MyBuild(build):
    def run(self):
        # Populate files to ./build/lib

setup(
    # ...
    cmdclass=dict(build=MyBuild)
)
```

Now, according to [this article](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#how-building-works) the setup script should copy everything in the `./build/lib` directory to the installation directory, which works as expected on **OSX** but not on **Ubuntu 14.04** where it ignores the `./build/lib` directory but rather installs files found in `./build/lib.<plat>`, which in turn doesn't work on **OSX** where the `./build/lib.<plat>` directory is ignored.

Is there a consistent, platform independent way to build and install files with **distutils**? The files are platform-independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `MyBuild.run()` method, populate files to the path given in `self.build_lib` instead of a hardcoded path.

```
from distutils.command.build import build
from distutils.core import setup

class MyBuild(build):
    def run(self):
        build_path = self.build_lib
        # Populate files to 'build_path'

setup(
    # ...
    cmdclass=dict(build=MyBuild)
)
```

Do not change the value of `self.build_lib` in `MyBuild.run()` as it is generated from command line arguments and/or various default values. The same goes for several other attributes such as `build_scripts`, `build_base`, `build_purelib`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution seems to be in setting the `build_lib` attribute of the `distutils.command.build.build` command class. The attribute is set in the `initialize_options()` method which we need to override to set the attribute:

```py
from distutils.command.build import build
from distutils.core import setup

class MyBuild(build):
    def initialize_options(self):
        build.initialize_options(self)
        self.build_lib = 'build/lib'

    def run(self):
        # Populate files to ./build/lib

setup(
    # ...
    cmdclass=dict(build=MyBuild)
)
```