# Change name of pip build directory

Tags: python, build, pip, setup.py

I'm using pip 20.2.3 on Linux to install additional packages (`extras_require['test']`) into a project that was first built using `python setup.py build -b _build`. In the project's directory, there's also a custom script called `build` (whose name I shouldn't change). When I run `pip install .[test]` it complains that `build` already exists and fails:

```
$ echo $TMPDIR
/.local/work/.ab/
$ pip install .[test]
[...]
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /[...]/venv/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/.local/work/.ab/pip-req-build-qxn943bk/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/.local/work/.ab/pip-req-build-qxn943bk/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /.local/work/.dv/pip-wheel-yhzxeqaj
       cwd: /.local/work/.ab/pip-req-build-qxn943bk/
  Complete output (5 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  error: could not create 'build': File exists
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for xxx
```

I've tried passing `--build` to pip but the option is marked as deprecated in man page and is obviously ignored.

Is there any other way I can make pip use another name for its build directory (e.g. `_build`), or is there a way to use `python setup.py build -b _build` to install only the `extras_require['test']` packages?

Comment: You need a [custom `build`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26257128/7976758). Set `self.build_lib = '_build'`.

Comment: @phd Thanks, that definitely improved things but it looks like there's another reference to `build` that isn't covered by this setting:  `running install_lib
  creating build
  error: could not create 'build': File exists`

Comment: Well, perhaps a custom `install_lib` too.